# Doesn't see public functions of a struct Golang

Tags: go

I don't see the public method of the struct that I defined. 
Can someone please let me understand why? 
Here is the code:

// DataSaver.go:

```
package DataStorage

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
)

type DataSaver struct {
   // doesn't relevant to my question
   fileName string
   file     *os.File
}

func PrintStr() {
   fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

Then, I have a main method in other class. I initialized the struct and I wanted to call to PrintStr() function. However, I can't call to this method. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.goland.org/). It will answer any questions about basic syntax and language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a method, it is just a function.

Import DataStorage (you should make it lower case) then you can call DataStorage.PrintStr()

Comment: I want to instance an object and then call to PrintStr() on this object. How can I achieve this? I don't see the public function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play around myself with this, and there are a few things to be careful of:

1. Make sure you import the package properly with respect to your GOPATH, e.g.

   import "github.com/some-repo/datastorage"

And ensure that your packages/repos are in your GOPATH and in the correct directories (go is very fussy about how you do this)

2. Refer to your function using the package name like so:

   func main(){
       DataStorage.PrintStr()
   }

The other poster is correct in that go conventions are to keep package names in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you dont have the concept of method receiver yet. Your method for the struct should be defined as below :

```
func (this DataSaver)PrintStr() {
   fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

or

```
func (this *DataSaver)PrintStr() {
   fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

which one you choose depends on you want to call the method on a pointer or not;